# Add Search Bar to Existing Header Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uisearchcontroller

I have been adding search boxes and search tab bars to my Swift 3 project based on the Ray Wenderlich tutorial (https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial)

This has worked well for most tables. However, one of my tables has a header that has been defined in the storyboard. If I use the code as shown below, it replaces the header that is defined in the storyboard, and also has some other side-effects.

I therefore want to know how to do one of the following:

a)append the search bar to the existing header using code
b)add a searchbar object in the storyboard and then set-up the outlet correctly so that my other search code references it.

I have the following code

In didload

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = true
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Active", "Not Active"]
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Extension above main class

```
extension ItemsViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating{
    func updateSearchResults(for: UISearchController) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}

extension ItemsViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        //filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
    }
}
```

Filter Code

```
    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = 
... filter logic ..     
tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

any thoughts would be much appreciated